# If four dice are thrown, what is the probability that the sum of numbers thrown up will be 15? How about 16?

Tags: probability, dice

> If four dice are thrown, what is the probability that the sum of numbers thrown up will be 15? How about 16?

What's a good method of finding the answer? I know that overall there are 1296 possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2354304/203736):

> It is the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in the expansion of the generating function $$(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x^1)^4=\left(\frac{x(1-x^6)}{1-x}\right)^4$$ which is $$1\cdot{{x}^{24}}+4\cdot {{x}^{23}}+10\cdot {{x}^{22}}+20\cdot {{x}^{21}}+35\cdot {{x}^{20}}+56\cdot {{x}^{19}}+80\cdot {{x}^{18}}\\+104\cdot {{x}^{17}}+125\cdot {{x}^{16}}+140\cdot {{x}^{15}}+146\cdot {{x}^{14}}+140\cdot {{x}^{13}}+125\cdot {{x}^{12}}+104\cdot {{x}^{11}}\\+80\cdot {{x}^{10}}+56\cdot {{x}^{9}}+35\cdot {{x}^{8}}+20\cdot {{x}^{7}}+10\cdot {{x}^{6}}+4\cdot {{x}^{5}}+1\cdot{{x}^{4}}$$
>
> so the answer is $140$.

Comment: Unless my computations are mistaken, this leads to 364/1296. But according to dice probability charts, the answer should be 140/1296

Comment: Fair enough, I'll see if I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There are $11$ different ways to throw 15:
$$6621\\6531\\6522\\6441\\6432\\6333\\5541\\5532\\5442\\5433\\4443$$
Now we have 4 types of throws (in brackets there are numbers of occurcences):
$$ABCD (2)\\ABCC(7)\\ABBB(2)\\AABB(0)\\AAAA(0)$$
Where $A,B,C,D$ are different numbers.
Now let's compute number of possible permutations of the above types (with positive numbers of occurences):

- $P_{ABCD}=4!$
- $P_{ABCC}= 4\cdot 3$
- $P_{ABBB}=4$

Thus there are 
$$X=2\cdot4! + 7\cdot 4\cdot 3 + 2\cdot 4 = 140 $$
events that lead to sum $15$.

Probabiblity is then equal to

$$P(15)=\frac{140}{6^4}=\frac{35}{324}$$